# What would cause incorrectly magnified text on iOS?

Tags: ios, uitextview

Can anyone comment on what might cause the following UI: one UITextView is magnified incorrectly; the other is drawn at the proper size. The code paths are identical and the user has not enabled text magnification on his device. These are not attributed strings. Is this an iOS bug?

[image]

UPDATE

This code shows how I am setting up the UITextView that is being drawn:

```
    chatMessageView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:tzvFrame];
    chatMessageView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:CHAT_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE];
    chatMessageView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
    chatMessageView.editable = NO;
    chatMessageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    chatMessageView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    chatMessageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.contentView addSubview:chatMessageView];

    ...

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showMenu)] autorelease];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [chatMessageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

I am setting color and frame on the UITextView in a few other places; otherwise there are no other properties on this UITextView.

The only weird/unique thing I am doing on this UITextView compared to other parts of my app is enabling a data detector.

Comment: It is probably not a bug. Have you tried using something like [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) or [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com/) or just ```NSLog```s to see what properties (like text size, scale, etc) are set on the large one?

Comment: I cannot consistently repro this issue -- would reveal or spark work on a signed, production iOS app on an end-users device who is reproing this?

Comment: They would both require you to be present to debug the issue, and can't be used on apps in the App Store. Have you eliminated possible causes like the user has a jailbroken device with font tweaks or an old OS?

Comment: One of the users was an employee of mine running the latest apple OS and he did not jailbreak, so no I don't believe this is the case...

Comment: Well, can you show some code for how those text fields are being populated & styled?

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious there, assuming CHAT_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE is actually a constant. Could it be something about how this view is being scrolled or otherwise transformed? Perhaps a table-view-cell reuse issue?